# IBM Worklight - Can the "Details" button be removed from the connection failure box?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Is there a setting that allows you to remove the Details option from the "Error - The application failed connecting to the service" message box?

Comment: In what situations and in what WL version does this Dialog pop-up? We have not encountered that. I was under the impression that the onFailure should handle a "failed connection to the service" case? We have our own dialogs with custom test and information to inform the end-user.

Comment: This is when you have the app configured to connect to server at startup.  If the server is down, this is the dialog that is displayed.

Comment: Yes you are correct, unlike the connection success, the onConnectionFailure completely overrides the failure sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is a **feature**, it it designed to allow the user to see rudimentary details about the connection failure. It should change in the future, but I of course cannot guarantee anything in this public space.

I suppose that you could delve into the framework JavaScruot in the yourEnvironment\native folder and find the relevant SimpleDialog code block with the "Details" button in it and remove it.

I don't know what may happen if you do this, though.

Comment: I don't think that it would ever be good to present a default Worklight dialog to an end-user of an app - it should always be custom app specific text and information!? Since Worklight is a framework and not an app my idea would be that it never shows any dialogs but only provides call-back hooks etc. for the developers to handle exceptions and situations ... or does the WL team have a different idea here?

Comment: Christian, you're an IBMer, use this ability to convey ideas and thoughts to product designers, or open feature requests for them to ponder upon for future releases, here (once it's not under maintenance...): https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25 Thanks.